# update nested list with user input

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

A function in a program I'm working on takes a list of quiz scores, and asks the user to input the name of a round and the score. If the round already exists, it appends the new score to the existing list, otherwise it adds the round and its score to the top-layer of the list:

```
lines = [['geography', '8', '4', '7'],
         ['tv and cinema', '4', '4', '8', '7', '7'],
         ['all creatures great and small', '7', '8'],
         ['odd one out', '4', '7'],
         ['music', '3', '5', '8', '8', '7'],
         ['how many', '4']]



roundName = input("Enter the name of the round to add: ")
score = input("Enter the score for that round: ")

for line in lines:
    if roundName in line:
        line.append(score)
lines.append([roundName, score])


#for line in lines:
#    if line[0] == roundName.lower().strip():
#        existingRound = lines.index(line)
#        lines[existingRound].append(score)
#    else:
#        newRound = [roundName, score]
#        lines.append(newRound)
```

The commented part represents my first few attempts. Entering `how many`, `3` should result in

```
lines = [['geography', '8', '4', '7'],
             ['tv and cinema', '4', '4', '8', '7', '7'],
             ['all creatures great and small', '7', '8'],
             ['odd one out', '4', '7'],
             ['music', '3', '5', '8', '8', '7'],
             ['how many', '4', '3']]
#actually results, in 
[['geography', '8', '4', '7'],
             ['tv and cinema', '4', '4', '8', '7', '7'],
             ['all creatures great and small', '7', '8'],
             ['odd one out', '4', '7'],
             ['music', '3', '5', '8', '8', '7'],
             ['how many', '4', '3'],
             ['how many', '3']]
```

I can't get the logic in the loop right. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should definitely use a dict for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for line in lines:
    if roundName in line:
        line.append(score)
lines.append([roundName, score])
```

Right here you're adding the new round to lines regardless of whether if it was present in lines already. Just use a boolean to indicate if adding to lines is needed and then change appending the new round to lines to a conditional:

```
add = True
for line in lines:
    if roundName in line:
        line.append(score)
        add = False
if add: lines.append([roundName, score])
```

If order doesn't matter though it would be much easier to use a dictionary:

```
lines = {'geography':['8', '4', '7'], 'tv and cinema': [...] ...}

roundName = input("Enter the name of the round to add: ")
score = input("Enter the score for that round: ")

if roundName in lines: lines[roundName].append(score)
else: lines[roundName] = [score]
```